# Assigning weight to multiple choice quiz

Tags: node.js, reactjs, angular

I have 25 multiple choice questions  with 4 answer choices per question. Each answer choice is worth 1-4 points. I have 2 questions that are free response and I want to score them based off how long it takes them to answer. These are the rules I want to imply: If completed in <15 seconds = 4 points; If completed in 15-25 seconds = 3 points; If completed in over 25 seconds = 2 points; If not completed = 1 point. Any ideas on how to go about this or links to any good videos?

I don’t know where to start to be honest.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like a slides and one question appear per slide and make that the user can't return to previous slides and when a slide appear to the screen you start a timer and the user has two option answer and ask for the next question or just ask for the next question without answering.

With this process you can generate the data you need. every time the user ask for the next question compute the score for the current question and add it to a variable that holds the sum of all scores.

The question is very vague to wright any code example but i hope this helps